# SMTP error: data not accepted

Tags: joomla-3.4, smtp

I'm trying to send an email with SMTP connection through my office365 account.

When I try to send form, I receive this message:

SMTP Error: data not accepted
SMTP ERROR: DATA NOT ACCEPTED

Comment: Double check your office365 account settings. You could also try sending through another service like gmail using SMTP to verify whether or not it is a Joomla issue or a mail server issue.

Comment: Yes all its correct. I can access in Firebird normally.